# Why is my content area stopping before my footer?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=960">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480">-->

<title>Habitat for Humanity Restore | Home</title>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
        <div class="headimg">
      <h2 class="slogan1">HOME IMPROVEMENT &amp; FURNITURE OUTLET</h2>
      <h3 class="slogan2"> A clean, happy place to find treasures</h3>
    </div>
  </header>



        <!--
        <div class="socialmedia"><img src="images/facebook-14.png" width="40" height="52" alt="FacebookSM">
        <img src="images/Pinterest-icon.png" width="40" height="52" alt="PinterestLogo">
        <img src="images/twitter-icon.png" width="40" height="52" alt="TwitterLogo"></div>
        -->

    </div> 
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DONATE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">VOLUNTEER</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

 <!-- Tony please fix text shadows, sidebar shadows and nagivation effects --> 

    <div id="sidebarleft">
        <ul class="sidebartextleft">
            <li class="pleftsidebar">ABOUT US</li>
            <li class="pleftsidebar">REPURPOSED </li>
            <li class="pleftsidebar">DONATE</li>
            <li class="pleftsidebar">VOLUNTEER</li>
            <li class="pleftsidebar">UNITED WAY </li>
            <li class="pleftsidebar">NEWSLETTER</li>
            <li class="pleftsidebar">EMAIL US</li>
            <li class="pleftsidebar">SEND US PHOTOS</li>
            <li class="pleftsidebar">MAP TO RESTORE</li>
            <li class="pleftsidebar">DIRECTIONS</li>
        </ul>

            <!--<p>CONTACT US </p>-->

        <div class="sidebartextleftsmall"> 
      Restore Facility<br/>
      200 South Larkin<br/>
          Joliet, IL. 60436<br/>
          P: 815-714-7100<br/>
          E: info@restorejoliet.org
        </div>
    </div>
<!--</div>-->
    <div id="sidebarright">
        <div class="sidebartextright">
            <p>FEATURED THIS WEEK:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightsidebarimg">
            <div class="featuredimg">
                <img src="images/furniture for sale.jpg" width="265" height="457" alt="furniture for sale">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebartextrightsmall"><span>Save our contact info to your smartphone</span>
            <img src="images/scancode.jpg" width="125" height="126" alt="Habitat Restore Contact Information Smartphone Code">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="captioned-gallery">
      <figure class="slider">
        <figure>
          <img src="images/restorelocationtext.png" alt="Will County Habitat For Restore Location">
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/slider2.jpg" alt="Worker setting up bookshelf">
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/slider3.jpg" alt="Warehouse selection">
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/slider4.JPG" alt="More Ware Selection Tables and fans">
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/slider5.JPG" alt="Household furniture warehouse selection">
        </figure>
      </figure>
    </div>
        <div id="box">
            <img src="images/habitatBox1.png" alt="Shop for repurposed materials" class="center" /> 
      <img src="images/habitatBox2.png" alt="Donate Heart" class="center" />
      <img src="images/habitatBox3.png" alt="Shop for repurposed materials" class="center" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebarbottom">
    <ul class="sidebartextleft">
        <li class="pleftsidebar"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li class="pleftsidebar"><a href="#">REPURPOSED</a></li>
        <li class="pleftsidebar"><a href="#">DONATE</a></li>
        <li class="pleftsidebar"><a href="#">VOLUNTEER</a></li>
        <li class="pleftsidebar"><a href="#">UNITED WAY</a></li>
        <li class="pleftsidebar"><a href="#">NEWSLETTER</a></li>
        <li class="pleftsidebar"><a href="#">EMAIL US</a></li>
        <li class="pleftsidebar"><a href="#">SEND US PHOTOS</a></li>
        <li class="pleftsidebar"><a href="#">MAP TO RESTORE</a></li>
        <li class="pleftsidebar"><a href="#">DIRECTIONS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div id="footer">2015 Will County Habitat for Humanity ReStore. All Rights Reserved.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm having an issue in which my content section suddenly stops before reaching the footer causing a black underlay to show up, I've looked into editing the wrapper size and height of the content container but cannot figure out what the issue may be, please help me out 
 [This below image is what the page is complete page should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aBB5.jpg)

CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
header {
    height: 106px;
    background-color: #d9e6ef;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%; 
}
#nav {
    height: 52px; 
    background-color: #51b948;
}
#nav ul {
    padding: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0 15px;
}
#nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
    color: #F4E9E9;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #406718;
    padding: 5px;
    border: thin solid #030303;
    width: 170px;
}
.socialmedia {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 45px; 
    padding: 8px 8px 0;
}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color:#FFF !important; 
}

#sidebarleft {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 784px; 
    background-color: #005596;
}
#sidebarright {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: 784px; 
    background-color: #005596;
}
#sidebarbottom {
    display: none;
}
.sidebartextleft {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bolder;
    height: 368px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.sidebartextright {
    position: relative; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 15px 0 20px 5px;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px; 
    height: 30px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.sidebartextlefthead {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: bold; 
    font-size: 22px; 
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pleftsidebar {
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #d5b89a;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    width: 80%
}

#content {
    width: 60%;
    height: 768px;
    float: left;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #dbf1da;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}

.rightsidebarimg {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.sidebartextrightsmall {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px; 
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 60px auto 0;
}
.sidebartextrightsmall span {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.sidebartextrightsmall img {
    max-width: 125px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.sidebartextleftsmall {
    margin: 200px 1px 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #c7b199;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-style: normal;
}
.featuredimg img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#box {
    text-align: center;

}
img.center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
.headimg {
    height: 106px;
    margin-left: 100px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    background: url(images/head.png) no-repeat;
}

h2.slogan1 {
    padding: 53px 0 0 220px ;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}
h3.slogan2 {
    padding-left: 220px ;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;    
}






@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}
body, figure { 
    margin: 0; 
    background: #101010;
}
div#captioned-gallery { 
    width: 90%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    border:5px solid #eaeaea;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    margin: 40px auto; 
}
figure.slider { 
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    font-size: 0; 
    animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
figure.slider figure { 
    width: 20%; 
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;  
    position: inherit; 
}
figure.slider img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
figure.slider figure figcaption { 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    color: #fff; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: .6rem; 
}

/* Bracket below closes desktop media query */
}





























@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
header {
    height: 106px;
    background-color: #d9e6ef;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 106px;
    background-color: #d9e6ef;
}
#nav {
    height: 52px; 
    background-color: #51b948;
}
#nav ul {
    padding: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0 15px;
}
#nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
    color: #F4E9E9;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #406718;
    padding: 5px;
    border: thin solid #030303;
    width: 140px;
}
.socialmedia {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 45px; 
    padding: 8px 8px 0;
}



#sidebarleft {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 784px; 
    background-color: #005596;
}
#sidebarright {
    display: none;
}
#sidebarbottom {
    display: none;
}
.sidebartextleft {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bolder;
    height: 368px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.sidebartextright {
    position: relative; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 15px 0 20px 5px;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px; 
    height: 30px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.sidebartextlefthead {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: bold; 
    font-size: 22px; 
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pleftsidebar {
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #d5b89a;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    width: 80%
}

#content {
    width: 75%;
    height: 768px;
    float: left;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #dbf1da;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}

.rightsidebarimg {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.sidebartextrightsmall {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px; 
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 60px auto 0;
}
.sidebartextrightsmall span {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.sidebartextrightsmall img {
    max-width: 125px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.sidebartextleftsmall {
    margin: 200px 1px 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #c7b199;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-style: normal;
}
.featuredimg img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


#box {
    text-align: center;

}
img.center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
.headimg {
    height: 106px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    background: url(images/head.png) no-repeat;
}

h2.slogan1 {
    padding: 53px 0 0 220px ;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}
h3.slogan2 {
    padding-left: 220px ;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;    
}






@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}
body, figure { 
    margin: 0; 
    background: #101010;
}
div#captioned-gallery { 
    width: 90%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    border:5px solid #eaeaea;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    margin: 40px auto; 
}
figure.slider { 
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    font-size: 0; 
    animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
figure.slider figure { 
    width: 20%; 
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;  
    position: inherit; 
}
figure.slider img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
figure.slider figure figcaption { 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    color: #fff; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: .6rem; 
}

/* Bracket below closes tablet media query */
}






























@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
header {
    height: 106px;
    background-color: #d9e6ef;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
#nav {
    background-color: #51b948;
}
#nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none; 
    border-bottom: 2px dotted white;
}
#nav ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
#nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
    color: #F4E9E9;
    padding: 20px;
}
#nav ul li a:link {
    text-decoration: none;

}
#nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #F4E9E9;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #51b948;
}
#nav ul li a:active {
    background: #406718;
}
.socialmedia {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 45px; 
    padding: 8px 8px 0;
}



#sidebarleft {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 784px; 
    background: #005596;
}
#sidebarright {
    display: none;
}
#sidebarbottom {
    width: 100%;
    background: #005596;
    text-align: center;
}
#sidebarbottom ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
#sidebarbottom ul li a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebarbottom ul li a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}
#sidebarbottom ul li a:hover {
    background: #005596;
}
#sidebarbottom ul li a:active {
    background: #d9e6ef;
}
.sidebartextleft {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: normal;
}
.sidebartextright {
    position: relative; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 15px 0 20px 5px;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px; 
    height: 30px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.sidebartextlefthead {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: bold; 
    font-size: 22px; 
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    background: #dbf1da;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #dbf1da;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}

.rightsidebarimg {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.sidebartextrightsmall {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px; 
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 60px auto 0;
}
.sidebartextrightsmall span {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.sidebartextrightsmall img {
    max-width: 125px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.sidebartextleftsmall {
    margin: 200px 1px 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #c7b199;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-style: normal;
}
.featuredimg img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


#box {
    text-align: center;
}
img.center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0;
    background: #42603C;

}
img.center:first-child {
    float: left;
}
img.center:last-child {
    float: right;
}
.headimg {
    height: 106px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/head.png) no-repeat center;
}

h2.slogan1 {
    display: none;
    /*
    padding: 35px 0 0 220px ;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    */
}
h3.slogan2 {
    display: none;
    /*
    padding-left: 220px ;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    */
}






@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}
body, figure { 
    margin: 0; 
    background: #101010;
}

div#captioned-gallery { 
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
figure.slider { 
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    font-size: 0; 
    animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
figure.slider figure { 
    width: 20%; 
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;  
    position: inherit; 
}
figure.slider img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
figure.slider figure figcaption { 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    color: #fff; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: .6rem; 
}

/* Bracket below closes phone media query */
}
```

Comment: Unable to replicate: **http://output.jsbin.com/pibaqakafa**. Can you create a jsBin snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You are closing one div more then you open div (tags). Count them and then look, which div should close at which point. You could for example search for all `div>` to get all open and closing div tags. One tip: take a look at the sourcecode in the browser, at least Firefox highlights wrong html syntax (too manny or to few tags or not matching tags) which makes it easy to find them.

**Edit:**
You close your content div after this div `<div id="box">....</div>`